# Can I abort command chkdsk /f/r/x running on 1 TB external hard drive and is stuck on stage 2 from past 12 days?

Tags: external-hard-drive, chkdsk

I have an external hard drive of 1 TB by WD with data worth of 480 GB. It was responding too slow during data retrieval. Went to couple of forums to find the solution and one suggested to run chkdsk command “chkdsk /f/r/x”. Now the hard drive is stuck on stage 2 of the command from past 12 days. Hard drive is blinking and looks like chkdsk is doing its work, but how long should I wait in a hope it will finish? Or is it just stuck there forever and waiting to be aborted? Please help.

Comment: After 12 days you can abort CHKDSK.  The drive likely has too many errors and needs to be replaced.

Comment: Thanks John. Hitting enter for couple of times did move the chkdsk to stage 4 and it’s progressing now. Thank you.

Comment: I posted an answer for you and if you find it to be acceptable, you can mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

> Now the hard drive is stuck on stage 2 of the command from past 12
> days

After 12 days,you can normally cancel CHKDSK.

There may be errors on the drive requiring drive replacement.  You can only determine this by allowing CHDKSK to finish (you said it was progressing after intervening), or by re-running CHKDSK.

If there are too many errors, back up what you can and replace the drive.